# c++ googlemocks : Getting a stack trace of an uninitialized call

Tags: c++, mocking, stack-trace, googlemock

Mock class looks like this :
struct MockClass
{
  MOCK_METHOD0( foo, void () );
};

If I forget to set an expected calls on a mock object, I get something like this :

```
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
    Function call: foo()
Stack trace:
```

and the stack trace is empty.

So, what has to be done in order to get the stack trace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Controlling_How_Much_Information_Google_Mock_Prints) :

> You can control how much Google Mock
>   tells you using the
>   --gmock_verbose=LEVEL command-line flag, where LEVEL is a string with
>   three possible values:
>   1. info: Google Mock will print all informational messages, warnings, and
>   errors (most verbose). At this
>   setting, Google Mock will also log any
>   calls to the ON_CALL/EXPECT_CALL
>   macros.
>   2. warning: Google Mock will print both warnings and errors (less
>   verbose). This is the default.
>   3. error: Google Mock will print errors only (least verbose).
>
> Alternatively, you can adjust the
>   value of that flag from within your
>   tests like so:
>   `::testing::FLAGS_gmock_verbose =
>   "error"`;

Using the *info* warning level will print the backtrace

Comment: Does not work for me, the stack trace is still empty.

Comment: I have the same issue, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814200/why-does-google-test-not-print-a-stack-trace-or-file-name) you need to define a macro, which is called to analyse the stack, as GTest doesn't bring its own functionality to do so, but I haven't found an implementation of this either...