# Why does Google Test not print a stack trace or file name?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

When I use Google Test and Google Mock, with diagnostic level set to "info", I get messages like this:

```
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
src/pkgtest/test_Foo.cpp:216:
    Function call: GetBar()
          Returns: 4-byte object <00-00 00-00>
Stack trace:

Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
src/pkgtest/test_Foo.cpp:126:
    Function call: GetBaz()
          Returns: {}
Stack trace:
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: CreateGrille(@0x7fff6a557050 { 16-byte object <80-D8 BB-01 00-00 00-00 70-D8 BB-01 00-00 00-00> })
    The mock function has no default action set, and its return type has no default value set." thrown in the test body.
```

I cannot find anything on the internet about why Google Test/Mock won't print a stack trace, or claims "unknown file". What do I need to do to teach it how to properly dump a stack trace?

(I'm on Linux using g++ 4.9, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Why not ask library vendor?

Comment: Why do you think it should return a stack trace?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Because it says "Stack trace:" with nothing after it. It sort of seems to hint that there should be something there.

Comment: @SergeyA I will try that.

Answer (score 3):

According to Samuel Benzaquen:

> gTest doesn't include a stack unwinder. You have to provide your own.
>   You can do this in include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h by defining
>   the GTEST_OS_STACK_TRACE_GETTER_ macro to point an implementation of
>   OsStackTraceGetterInterface.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/googletestframework/WMJuxAE7y-A/3FjexkRpEQAJ

Comment: Any examples of this in use?

Comment: It seems this behavior may now be configured by default. If `GTEST_OS_STACK_TRACE_GETTER_` *isn't* set it [defaults to `OsStackTraceGetter`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e589a337/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L6019), which claims to be ["a working implementation of the OsStackTraceGetterInterface interface"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e589a337/googletest/src/gtest-internal-inl.h#L454). I wonder if this macro isn't supposed to be used; it's only [mentioned in "internal" docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e589a337/googletest/include/gtest/internal/custom).

Comment: But, if it helps, [Chromium sets this macro to a custom class](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/de3bda33ad0198583fac230f1e00f7a461c08879), so perhaps `OsStackTraceGetter` isn't actually sufficient.